# Connecting node-opcua client with multpile opcua-server

Tags: opc-ua, node-opcua

Now I have been exploring OPC UA, I have used node-opcua npm package for both server and client side. Here my requirement is, I need to connect the OPC UA-client with multiple servers.

When I learned this OPC UA theoretically, I saw that this (Connecting  a client with multiple servers) is possible in OPC UA. But in node-opcua I could not do this. For now, I connected the client with a single OPC UA-server.

[click to see the node-opcua npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-opcua)

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to connect the OPC-UA-client with multiple OPC UA-servers, when using node-opcua npm package?
2. If it is possible, what should I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a instance of OPCUAClient for each connection.

Comment: I'm seeking clarification here. Suppose I have a server running OPC UA with 100 devices connected to it. If I wish to retrieve data from all these 100 devices, do I need to establish 100 individual OPC UA client connections?

Comment: Absolutely. just create as many OPCUAClient instances as needed and establish a connection with one server with one OPCUAClient instance.

Comment: But, Is this the efficient way?

Comment: >But, Is this the efficient way ?
Yes, one client handle a single connection , Clients are lightweight and  don't consume much ressources